# Flutter: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando fazer uma checagem através do token:

Se houver token, exibe a página `Home` e, se não houver, exibe a página `Login`.

Tentei desta forma:

**main.dart:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    // Create storage
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    checkHome() async {
    // Read value 
    String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    if(token != null){
      return HomePage();
    }else{
      return LoginPage();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cadê meu pet?',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
      home: checkHome(),
    );
  }
}
```

Porém, eu estou recebendo:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Eu não posso retornar a home/login através dessa função?

Também tentei:

```
void main() async {
  // Set default home.
  Widget _defaultHome = new LoginPage();

  // Read value 
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
  if (token != null) {
    _defaultHome = new HomePage();
  }

  // Run app!
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Cadê meu pet?',
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
    home: _defaultHome,
  ));
}
```

Comment: Seu método `checkHome()` possui a atribuição de assíncrono. Isso ocorre por ter inserido na assinatura dele o `async`, com isso o retorno é algo no futuro (`Future` como está recebendo no erro). Já o componente que a classe do flutter está esperando é do tipo `Widget` e como seu retorno é outro tipo ocorre o erro. Uma das soluções para seu problema seria a definição de uma variável que recebesse a resolução do método futuro e a partir dela escolher com um ternário qual página deseja exibir.

Comment: como posso receber a resolução do meu método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu retorno mostra que o componente espera que seja passado para ele um elemento do tipo `Widget` mas você está passando um elemento do tipo `Future<Widget>`. Futuros são retornados sempre que o método possui em sua assinatura a declaração `async`.

No seu caso um exemplo que pode utilizar é:

#### Exemplo com StatefulWidget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // Create storage
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Variável de controle
  bool temToken = false;

  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  checkHome() async {
    // Read value
    String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    setState(() {
      temToken = token != null;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    checkHome();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cadê meu pet?',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),

      /// Declaração do ternário para escolher qual page exibir
      home: temToken ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Home"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Login"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Existem outras abordagens que poderiam ser utilizadas, mas diante do exemplo que passou na pergunta, essa é uma das formas simples para este cenário específico que apresentou.

Comment: Legal, eu adicionei um debugPrint(temToken.toString()); e ele retorna true, porém na condição ternária está retornando a tela de login, o elemento a esquerda da condição é o true, certo? não deveria ir para a tela home?

Comment: Analisei melhor e agora ele está pegando o valor de  bool temToken = false;, por isso mostra a tela de login, porém mesmo quando altera pra true ele já renderizou a tela de login e não altera pra tela home.

Comment: Pelo que entendi do seu cenário essa é a primeira tela do app. Como ele depende de uma condição aconselho utilizar um `StateFull`. Vou adicionar o exemplo com o StateFull para que possa acompanhar melhor.

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou conforme o esperado. Obrigado, deu pra aprender um pouco

Comment: Para ficar mais simples então para futuras consultas da comunidade, removi o exemplo que não funcionou como esperado e deixei apenas o exemplo que atendeu a demanda.